# Mailchimp subscription metadata

Tags: ruby, api, mailchimp

Is it possible to add metadata to user mailchimp subscription?

This is my mailchimp method for subscription :

```
def subscribe_to_newsletter
    MAILCHIMP.listSubscribe(id: MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID,
                            email_address: email,
                            double_optin: false,
                            merge_vars: {FNAME:firstname,LNAME:surname})
  end
```

I'm wondering can I put some metadata like some unique property for the object being subscribed, or the property being common for more than one object?

Or is there a way to do this mailchimp way?

Answer (score 1):

You can define new merge_vars using [listMergeVarAdd](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listmergevaradd.func.php). Once you've done that you can include them in the `listSubscribe` merge_vars.

Comment: Thx for pointing that out. And here is the link to the same in API v2.0: [/lists/merge-var-add](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/merge-var-add.php)